# What is this nonparametric goodness-of-fit test?

Tags: chi-squared-test, nonparametric, goodness-of-fit, kolmogorov-smirnov-test, probability-inequalities

I wrote down a goodness-of-fit test that I have not seen before.
However, it is quite elementary and has many applications, so I
bet it must have been known. Could someone tell me its name?

**Setup.** The setup is the same as the [Pearson's $\chi^2$
goodness-of-fit
test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson%27s_chi-squared_test).
Fix $N$ and a finite outcome set $o = \{o_1, \ldots, o_r\}$. Each
$o_i$ has a certain probability $p_i$ (unknown to the user) to be
drawn with $\sum p_i = 1$. Draw $N$ i.i.d. samples from $o$, and
let $O_i$ be the amount of $o_i$ drawn. From $O_i$ the user wants
to test the null hypothesis.

$$H_0: p_i = p_i' \quad\text{ for each } i.$$

**Usual Statistics.** The statistics usually used for this problem is the Pearson's statistics [4]. It examines the statistics $$P_N := \sum_{i=1}^r
\frac{(O_i - Np_i')^2}{Np_i'},$$ whose $N \to \infty$ limit has density function being the chi-squared with $r-1$ freedom $\chi^2_{(r-1)}$ [3].

**My Statistics.** My test statistics is the $L^2$-deviation $\sum_{i=1}^r \left|\frac{O_i}{N} - p_i'\right|^2$. The underlying inequality resembles the DKW inequality (it provides a clear convergence rate for the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test [1]). It is quite simple
and only uses Markov's inequality and $\text{Var}(O_i)=p_i(1-p_i)$: Given any $\epsilon >0$,

$$P\left(\sum_{i=1}^r \left|\frac{O_i}{N} - p_i'\right|^2 > \epsilon \right) 
\leq \frac{E\left(\sum_{i=1}^r \left(\frac{O_i}{N} - p_i'\right)^2\right)}{\epsilon} 
= \frac{\sum_{i=1}^r p_i' (1-p_i')}{N^2\epsilon}
\leq \frac{1 - \frac{1}{r^2}}{N^2\epsilon}
$$

where the last equality holds under the null hypothesis.
**Hence under the null hypothesis, one has a bound for the
probability that deviates from the target $\{p_i'\}$, from which tests and confidence intervals can be easily provided.**
One drawback is that this only decays in $O(\frac{1}{N^2})$.

**Question.**

What is the name of the tests related to this inequality?

**Reference.**

- [1] [Dvoretzky–Kiefer–Wolfowitz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dvoretzky%E2%80%93Kiefer%E2%80%93Wolfowitz_inequality)
- [3] [The rate of convergence of some asymptotically chi-square distributed statistics by Stein’s method-[Robert E. Gaunt and Gesine Reinert]](https://browse.arxiv.org/pdf/1603.01889.pdf)
- [4] It admits a one-parameter family generalization, namely the Cressie-Read statistics. This includes Pearson statistic ($\lambda=1$), the log likelihood ratio
  statistic ($\lambda = 0$), the Freeman-Tukey statistic
  ($\lambda=-1/2$), the modified log likelihood ratio statistic
  ($\lambda=-1$), and the Neyman modified chi squared ($\lambda=-2$). All of them tend to $\chi^2_{(r-1)}$ as well [3].

Comment: Side comment: I’d be interested to know what motivated you to be interested in large-sample approximations that may not apply to a sample you actually have in hand?

Comment: @FrankHarrell Thanks for your question. I find DKW inequality very satisfying. It provides a bound for every parameter in your space (more precisely, in the case of DKW the space is all singly variated cdf, and in my case ($r$ fixed) the space is all discrete $p_i$ summing to $1$). With "my statistics" and the inequality, the same thing is achieved. But with Pearson statistics and alike, we don't have such clear bounds on all possible $\{p_i'\}$. We either reject or accept the null, but don't have a quantitative idea how much it's deviated. (Btw why do you call it large-sample?)

Comment: Sounds like we need to distinguish mathematical interest from applied statistical analysis.

Comment: Since I've not seen it before, I'll suggest "Student's P."

Comment: Why should your choice of test statistic have any use?  Under conditions that apply in chi-squared testing, I don't think it will lead to any kind of admissible test.  What's different about your setting?

Comment: @FrankHarrell I was curious and studied ways to compare statistical tests but found that it's quite involving. How would you compare my test with Pearson's chi-square? Are you using asymptotic relative efficiency as a judger? How do you tell that my test requires large-sample? It converges in $O(1/n^2)$ which isn't too bad.

Comment: @whuber In practice, at least in the hypothesis testing framework, people seem to only care about acceptance or rejection of the null. But for me, I want to quantify how much the null fails, not just to get a binary decision. Hence it is very important to get explicit bounds for the likelihood function. -- The most appealing property of "my test", which is inspired from DKW inequality, is that the likelihood function is bounded by the inequality immediately: Indeed, forget about the null hypothesis for a moment, and suppose we get data $d_i:=\frac{O_i}{N}$.

Comment: @whuber Then for **any** parameter $\theta = (q_1,\ldots,q_r) \in \Theta$, we compute $\sum_i (d_i-q_i)^2 = \epsilon_\theta$. Then by the inequality we know immediately that $L(\theta)=P(d_i|\theta)\leq \frac{1}{N^2\epsilon_\theta}$! -- AFAIK, it is very difficult to do the same for the Pearson chi square test for finite $N$. Also, I am yet to see a reason why Pearson's test is intrinsically better. Could it be that it's more efficient in any sense (e.g. ARE model mentioned above)? I haven't computed their asymptotic relative efficiency, but $O(1/N^2)$ seems promising to me.

Comment: @Student I would form a Bayesian model, then given the model, prior, and data I would get exact inference for any sample size.